# How to align the paginator in primeng?

Tags: angular, primeng, paginator

I'm using primeng datatable along with the paginator. I'm using the ng-template to display the record information along with the paginator. But, they are not properly aligned in the mobile view. Please see below screenshot.

Since, the paginator is coming from the primeng I'm not able to use grid or style it. Any idea how to fix this?

```
<ng-template pTemplate="paginatorleft" let-state class="ui-g">
      <div class="ui-g-12">
        Showing {{ state.page * state.rows + 1 }} to
        {{ state.rows * (state.page + 1) }} of {{ state.totalRecords }} entries
      </div>
  </ng-template>
```

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/C50UQ.jpg)

Comment: have yo try these `[responsive]="true"` in yout `<p--table>`

Comment: Yes, my p-table is responsive. In mobile mode, the rows are stacked nicely. No problem with that. Only the paginator is not being displayed properly for smaller screens (iphone 6 and below)